# Model publishing starts after 8 hours after C4R command executing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I've implemented a service, that publish all models, which were modified with C4R. I've used tutorial on the Forge site.

Sometimes, when i execute command for publishing models, it returns status:commited, but it starts to publish after 7-8 hours.

As my models are big, it takes 3-4 hours to publish it, so i receive webhook after 12 hours after execution of the command.

How to fix that? Is there some publishing queue or something else to look into?

Answer (score 1):

Forge web services, like most web services, have a job queuing system. At busy times your job may take extra time to start. Or, based on external dependencies, it may need to wait for some other job to finish.

That said, when you post to publish endpoint, check the response, it should contain a `request-id` header that we can use to track down what's happening. Please share that so I can check our logs.

**UPDATE**

The system will not emit a *publish completed* event, your application should watch for `dm.version.added` instead. Looking at your specific request, there is nothing unexpected, just note that publishing can take a long time depending on the number of models, size of models and the length of the publishing queue.

Comment: ID: 74027c20-f57a-4e83-a95f-caa639480d69.

I sent the command to publish, but it still hasn't started.

Comment: I've created a webhook for that.But publish didn't start, it started only the next day,when i executed publish command one more time, and got response id: 8937da8b-8ec2-4205-8588-2b65f3727cb5.

I mean, that I created service,for everyday publishing modified models, but it doesn't works well, because sometimes, the publishing job doesn't starts.